# accessor not working in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, accessor

I have a model that have one accessor inside it

```
class Test extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'subject','date',
   ];


    public function getSubjectAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }
}
```

When I call model, accessor does not work
I read all documents and Q&A , but ... 
My Laravel version in 5.5

In the model I have a method for fetch data

```
public function get_specific_subject($id){
    $subject = DB::table("subjects")
        ->where("id", "=", $id)
        ->first();

    return $subject;
}
```

And I am calling this method in my controller by bellow code

```
    $subject = new Test();
    $subject = $subject->get_specific_subject($subject_id);
    dd($subject);
```

The dd result is :

```
    +"id": 5
    +"subject": "testing subject"
    +"date": "2018-01-17"
    +"created_at": "2018-01-13 15:08:41"
    +"updated_at": "2018-01-13 15:08:41"
```

Comment: Where is $subject_id coming from?

Comment: What are you expecting? Can you show the output of `dd($subject)`.

Comment: may be you are using accessor in wrong model.

Comment: You are dumping the whole model. You need to dd() $subject—>subject if you want the attribute

Comment: @LewisJohnson Is it important ? for example it is static variable . $subject_id = 1;

Comment: @kerbholz I've edited my question and add it

Comment: @hrzrahimi is your test model represents subject table??

Comment: See if `dd(\App\Test::find($id)` does what you want (replace $id with an existing id). Accessors take effect when using Eloquent.

Answer (score 2):

You are using DB to fetch your record , instead do this in your controller :

```
  $subject= Test::find($subjectId);
  dd($subject);
```

and in your model , add this line :

```
  protected $table = 'subjects';
  public $primaryKey='id';
```

Comment: Nothing changed!! Again the accessor does not working

Comment: It does not matter. But I try it and nothing changed

Comment: ok then try to rename model name  Test to Subject , and file name to Subject.php

Comment: This is the correct answer. Your accessors only work if you call the model where you defined them. They don't work with `\DB` facade. If for whatever reason this solution doesn't work, you should first set up your models correctly.

Comment: @SaurabhMistry Definitely not

Comment: @devk As I said before, I test suggested code and again accessor doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'subjects';
   protected $fillable = [
       'subject','date',
   ];

   public function getSubjectAttribute($value)
   {
       return ucfirst($value);
   }
}
```

And in controller

```
public function view($subjectId){
    $subject = Test::find($subjectId);
    dd($subject->toArray());
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed!! Again the accessor does not working

Comment: This is wrong. He wants the "subjects" table, not the test table.

Comment: Please check whether value present in `$subjectId`

Comment: Please check the latest code. here add '$subject->toArray()'.Because accessor will be called only after  the model turns to json or array

Comment: @PraveenTamil It's not really important. for example $subjectId = 1

Comment: @LewisJohnson As I understood OP wants the field 'subject' from the Test model, that's why he made `getSubjectAttribute()`

Comment: @kerbholz It's all very confusing. OP should just start again.

Comment: Just put `dd($subject->toArray());`

Answer (score 0):

Use `$subject->subject` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this (use your model):

```
public function get_specific_subject($id){
    $subject = Subject::where("id", "=", $id)
        ->first();
    return $subject;
}
```

Comment: There is the find() method, which is a shortcut for where('id', ...)->first().
Also this method should be static. And is just useless then, because he can use Subject::find($id) where it is needed